# how to integrate login system of gmail in my application?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a web application where users can sign in with their id, or facebook id, twitter id or gmail id. I have done this with facebook and twitter so far. But I am running into problems with gmail. In facebook and twitter case, I have created an application going to developers/..../new/app like this and get appid for both facebook and twitter, and integrated both in my login system, but in case of gmail I'm confused. Is there any process/thing, I mentioned above in case of gmail a/c?

I am doing my project in PHP CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Authentication Federation, and Google documents it in their Google Developers site. In summary, they support OpenID:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: Can you have any demo please ?

Comment: thaks for the advice and link dai but there is too much information for me to extract the imp ones.Can't it be a little bit specific?

Comment: Search for OpenID examples with PHP. Here is one I found straight-away: http://devzone.zend.com/1254/getting-started-with-openid-and-php/ (but I hope you're not planning on being a copy-and-paste programmer?)

Comment: Actually, Google is phasing out OpenID in favor of OAuth2.  OpenID will continue working but OAuth2 is preferred and easier to integrate with.